# SQL Rolling Average by Day of Week (or Date minus 7)

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a query that pulls data and groups it to:

```
Date        Type        Total
3/1/2016    Sales       9
3/1/2016    Support     8
3/1/2016    Service     5
3/1/2016    Other       48
3/2/2016    Sales       42
3/2/2016    Support     86
3/2/2016    Service     67
3/2/2016    Other       25
3/2/2016    VIP         12
3/3/2016    Sales       46
3/3/2016    Support     45
3/3/2016    Service     78
3/3/2016    Other       70
3/3/2016    VIP         26
```

I want to include a rolling average as well. So for 3/1/2016 Sales the rolling average would be for the 10 prior Tuesdays. Essentially:

```
select average(Total) where Date in ('2/23/2016','2/16/2016','2/9/2016','2/2/2016','1/26/2016','1/19/2016','1/12/2016','1/5/2016','12/29/2015','12/22/2015') and Type = "Sales"
```

Is there a way to efficiently do this in 1 query?

Comment: Are you sure this is SQL Server as dates are not stored in that format?

Comment: Sorry, that's the results from a query 
CAST(DateTime AS DATE)as Date

Answer (score 1):

Use something like this:

```
SELECT AVG(tbl.Total)
FROM  tbl
WHERE DATEPART(WEEKDAY, tbl.[Date]) = 3 AND tbl.[Date] > DATEADD(DAY, -7 * 10, GETDATE())
AND tbl.[Type] = 'Sales'
GROUP BY DATEPART(WEEKDAY, tbl.[Date])
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following where you would place your query in the `Qry` placeholder in both inner and outer queries. Alternatively, you can integrate the subquery inline with original query. All 10 weekly dates are explicitly specified in the `IN()` clause since you require only those select dates (i.e., Tuesdays, Wednesdays) relative to the row's corresponding date.

```
SELECT dT.Date, dT.Type, dT.Total,

       (SELECT Avg(sub.Total)
        FROM Qry sub
        WHERE sub.Date IN
              (DateAdd(d, -7,  dT.Date),
               DateAdd(d, -14, dT.Date),
               DateAdd(d, -21, dT.Date),
               DateAdd(d, -28, dT.Date),
               DateAdd(d, -35, dT.Date),
               DateAdd(d, -42, dT.Date),
               DateAdd(d, -49, dT.Date),
               DateAdd(d, -56, dT.Date),
               DateAdd(d, -63, dT.Date),
               DateAdd(d, -70, dT.Date))    
        AND sub.Type = dT.Type) As RollAvg

FROM Qry dT
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up going with temptables
First I created a #TempTotal

```
Select Date, DATENAME(dw,Date) as DayName, Type, Count(*) as Total
INTO #TempTotal
From tbl
Where Date >=@StartDate and Date <= @EndDate
Group by Date, DayName, Type
```

Then I created #TempAverage which:

```
Select DayName, Type, avg(Total) 
INTO #TempAverage
from 
(
select Date, DATENAME(dw,Date) as DayName, Type, Count(*) as Total
from tbl
where Date >=DateAdd(d, -70,  @StartDate) and Date <= @StartDate
Group by Date, DayName, Type
) Totals
Group by DayName, Type
```

Finally, we have a simple joining

```
Select TT.Date, Type, TT.Total, TA.Average
FROM
#TempTotal TT
Left Join #TempAverage TA on TA.DayName = TT.DayName and TA.Type= TT.Type
```

Comment: You did not need temp tables as each query could have been nested in final. Plus your date `where` condition takes ALL dates from 70 days ago, much different from original posted need of select week days (i.e., last 10 Tuesdays).